# ImageMagick is converting only the first page of the pdf

Tags: pdf, imagemagick

I am having some trouble with ImageMagick.

I have installed GhostScript v9.00 and ImageMagick-6.6.7-1-Q16 on Windows 7 - 32Bit

When I run the following command in cmd

**convert D:\test\sample.pdf D:\test\pages\page.jpg**

only the first page of the pdf is converted to pdf. I have also tried the following command

**convert D:\test\sample.pdf D:\test\pages\page-%d.jpg**

This creates the first jpg as page-0.jpg but the other are not created.
I would really appreciated if someone can shed some light on this. Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

I have ran the command using -debug "All"

one of the many lines out put says:

```
2011-01-26T22:41:49+01:00 0:00.727 0.109u 6.6.7 Configure Magick[5800]: nt-base.c/NTGhostscriptGetString/1008/Configure
registry: "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\GPL Ghostscript\9.00\GS_DLL" (failed)
```

Could it maybe have something to do with GhostScript after all?

Comment: That last command is correct, does the PDF have multiple pages, can you access them directly?

Comment: Yeah when I executed this command  convert .\test\sample.pdf[2] .\test\pages\page.jpg it did convert the second page.

Comment: @ElGabbu: But [2] is for the ***third*** page. [0] is the ***first*** one (counting is zero-based...)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can specify which page to convert by putting a number in [] after the filename:

```
convert D:\test\sample.pdf[7] D:\test\pages\page-7.jpg
```

It should have, however, converted all pages to individual images with your command.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply you are correct infact when I executed the following command  convert .\test\sample.pdf[2] .\test\pages\page.jpg it did convert the second page of the pdf correctly. I have done the same test on another machine and got the same problem. Could it be something wrong with some version i am using GhostScript or ImageMagick?

Comment: Could be. My understanding is that 'convert' will do all pages of a PDF unless you specifically restrict to a single one with that `[]` notation. So... either your version's goofy or there's something else going on.

Comment: Well it turns out to be something wrong with the pdf :S ... tried testing with other PDF files ... and managed to convert a 129 page pdf successfully. I am gonna do some more tests for now see how it goes. Thanks again for your interest. I m gonna mark ur answer right just to show my appreciation.

Comment: Adding [xx] gives me "unable to open image" no such file or directory under windows !?

Comment: **`[7]`** would be the ***eighth*** page. **`[0]`** is the ***first*** one. Counting is zero-based...

Comment: @KurtPfeifle I would say that counting is usually done with natural numbers and starts at 1. Indexing, however, is often zero-based and is how I would refer to what is happening here.

Comment: @Erik: Ok, you are right: I should have made the distinction between "counting" and "indexing".

Answer (score 18):

By the way if you need to convert first and second pages then provide in array comma separated values

```
convert D:\test\sample.pdf[0,1] D:\test\pages\page.jpg
```

Resulting JPEG files will be named:

- for page 1: `page-0.jpg`
- for page 2: `page-1.jpg`

You can also do

```
convert D:\test\sample.pdf[10,15,20-22,50] D:\test\pages\page.jpg
```

Resulting JPEG files will be named:

- for page 11: `page-10.jpg`
- for page 16: `page-15.jpg`
- for page 21: `page-20.jpg`
- for page 22: `page-21.jpg`
- for page 23: `page-22.jpg`
- for page 51: `page-50.jpg`

May be it will help to someone.

Answer (score 6):

According to the site admin at the ImageMagick forum:

> ImageMagick uses the pngalpha device when it finds an Adobe
>   Illustrator PDF. Many of these are a single page. Ideally, Ghostscript
>   would support a device that allows multiple PDF pages with
>   transparency but it doesn't...
>
> Easy fix. **Edit delegates.xml and change pngalpha to pnmraw.**

This worked for me. I don't know if it introduces any other problems however.

See [this post from their forums](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=18001).

Answer (score 5):

I found this solution which convert all pages in the pdf to a single jpg image:

```
montage input.pdf -mode Concatenate -tile 1x output.jpg
```

montage is included in ImageMagick.

Tested on ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 on Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: Can anyone help me where should I write this command to convert all pages of PDF to single image. I have Imagemagick installed in my system.

Comment: @RahulSinha open a console window and navigate to the location of your pdf. Execute the command there, if the montage executable is not in the path, you should locate it first.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar problem with GhostScript. This can be solver with using `%03d` iterator in the output file name. Here is example:

```
gs -r300 -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE#pngalpha -sOutputFile=output-%03d.png input.pdf
```

Here is the reference with detailed information: https://ghostscript.com/doc/current/Devices.htm