# View pdf image in an iPython Notebook

Tags: python, pdf, jupyter-notebook

The following code allows me to view a `png` image in an iPython notebook. Is there a way to view `pdf` image? I don't need to use IPython.display necessarily. I am looking for a way to print a pdf image in a file to the iPython notebook output cell.

```
## This is for an `png` image
from IPython.display import Image

fig = Image(filename=('./temp/my_plot.png'))
fig
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

The problem you (and others) face is that PDFs cannot be displayed directly in the browser.
The only possible way to get something similar is to use an image-converter to create a PNG or JPG out of the PDF and display this one.
This could be done via imagemagick and a custom display function.

### Update 1

A simple solution is to use wand (http://docs.wand-py.org) a python-imagemagick binding. I tried with Ubuntu 13.04:

[image: wand session in ipython]

In text form:

```
from wand.image import Image as WImage
img = WImage(filename='hat.pdf')
img
```

For a multi-page pdf, you can get e.g. the second page via:

```
img = WImage(filename='hat.pdf[1]')
```

### Update 2

As recent browsers support to display pdfs with their embedded pdf viewer a possible alternative solution based on an iframe can be implemented as

```py
class PDF(object):
  def __init__(self, pdf, size=(200,200)):
    self.pdf = pdf
    self.size = size

  def _repr_html_(self):
    return '<iframe src={0} width={1[0]} height={1[1]}></iframe>'.format(self.pdf, self.size)

  def _repr_latex_(self):
    return r'\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{{{0}}}'.format(self.pdf)
```

This class implements html and latex representations, hence the pdf will also survive a nbconversion to latex. It can be used like

```
PDF('hat.pdf',size=(300,250))
```

With Firefox 33 this results in 
[image]

Comment: Very cool!  Can wand pick a particular page out of a pdf?  If so, an example of that would be great.

Comment: Yeah, you can use `hat.pdf[1]` to access the second page of hat.pdf. It's exactly the same as with standard IM see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/4809314/2870069

Comment: How do you display multiple pages?  IE `hat.pdf[1-5]`

Comment: @AdamHughes what do you want to see in such a case? Wand converts the pdf to an Image, hence do you want a large image of all pages

Comment: Ah, hmm I see.  Well I guess just from a usecase, i'd like to view several pages of the PDF; so I guess a long image?

Comment: @AdamHughes I 've updated my answer to show a second possibility based on an iframe with embedded pdf viewer. Maybe this approach is more appropriate for you. If not, I'd suggest to use pdfnup to create a onepage pdf with all your pages arranged as desired and subsequently create the wand image.

Answer (score 81):

To show pdf-s inside ipython/jupyter notebooks you can use `IFrame`

```
from IPython.display import IFrame
IFrame("./samples/simple3.pdf", width=600, height=300)
```

Here is the screenshot

[image: pdf preview in ipython/jupyter notebook]

Comment: Smart solution, and useful for so much more

Comment: Hi can we put the link of files stored on a repository in Github and get it embedded like this? I tried but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Extremely important note: the target PDF file **must be in a subdirectory of the directory `jupyter notebook` was run on**.

Comment: Even if the pdf is in a subfolder, it doesn't work in Safari as of now. In firefox and chrome it works.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Jakob's excellent answer recommending the Wand bindings for ImageMagick:

If your PDF contains vector graphics, use the `resolution` keyword to control the size of the rendered image. ImageMagick's default value is 72 dpi. Higher values yield more pixels.

```
from wand.image import Image as WImage
img = WImage(filename='hat.pdf', resolution=100) # bigger
img
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming a multi-image pdf called Rplots.pdf

The following works in the jupyter notebook cell. For installation I used

```
pip install Wand
```

This code pastes into a cell

```
from wand.image import Image  

imageFromPdf = Image(filename='Rplots.pdf')  
pages = len(imageFromPdf.sequence)  

image = Image(  
  width=imageFromPdf.width,  
  height=imageFromPdf.height * pages  
)  
for i in range(pages):  
  image.composite(  
  imageFromPdf.sequence[i],  
  top=imageFromPdf.height * i,  
  left=0  
)  
image.format="png"  
image
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a better way to do this, since

- with wand you need to install the MagickWand library
- with IFrame you are not flexible with the directories

I would do it like this:

```
    from PIL import Image
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import fitz

    your_path = # YOUR PATH
    doc = fitz.open(your_path)
    MAX_PAGES = 1

    zoom = 2 # to increase the resolution
    mat = fitz.Matrix(zoom, zoom)

    for i, page in enumerate(doc):
        pix = page.get_pixmap(matrix=mat)
        img = Image.frombytes("RGB", [pix.width, pix.height], pix.samples)

        # display images
        plt.figure(figsize=(7,7), facecolor="w")
        plt.xticks(color="white")
        plt.yticks(color="white")
        plt.tick_params(bottom = False)
        plt.tick_params(left = False)

        plt.imshow(img)

        if i > MAX_PAGES - 1:
            break
```

Comment: This is a great answer if you have to run everything in a notebook and can't install packages via the CLI and your pdfs are in S3. I am running on sagemaker and just had to add some small changes for opening the file:  `s3 = boto3.client('s3');
pdf_file = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=pdf_file_name);
file_content = pdf_file['Body'].read();
with fitz.open(stream=file_content, filetype="pdf") as doc:
    for i, page in enumerate(doc):`