# Embedding local pdf image in jupyter notebook with IFrame just produces a gray box

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am trying to embed a local PDF image file into a jupyter notebook run in jupyter-lab as follows:

```
from IPython.display import IFrame
plot_fn = 'example_data/example_cNMF/example_plot.pdf'
IFrame(plot_fn, width=600, height=400)
```

But this just produces a gray box:
[image: Output of attempt to display pdf]

Any idea what is going on or how I can fix this? I am using Python 3.6, jupyter==1.0.0 jupyterlab==0.32.1 matplotlib==2.2.2 ipython==6.5.0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [View pdf image in an iPython Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19470099/view-pdf-image-in-an-ipython-notebook)

Comment: I have this same problem.  Using Chrome.  Not at liberty to switch to Firefox.   There must be a fix for this that would work with all PDFs, no?

Answer (score 2):

What browser are you using? I was using Safari on MacAir, and had this problem.

Changing the browser to Firefox solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If downgrading is an option, downgrading to the following versions allow pdfs to be displayed in chrome:

```
pip install tornado==4.5.3 notebook==5.1
```

or with Anaconda:

```
conda install tornado=4.5.3 notebook=5.1
```

Alternatively installing the following plugin will also solve the issue:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pdf-viewer/oemmndcbldboiebfnladdacbdfmadadm?hl=en