# Open and view pdfs iteratively in Python, but stay on the shell

Tags: python

I am writing a short script that will loop through the pdf files in a directory, open them iteratively and let me classify them. The code I've written almost does everything I want. It loops through the files and opens and closes them.  Note I'm working on Linux.

However, the cursor is not always staying on the shell, and I don't want to have to keep pressing Alt-tab. Does anyone know a way to use subprocess to run system commands, but to never move away from the shell when Python is running?

A simplified version of what I've got so far:

```
import signal
import os
import subprocess
import glob

files = glob.glob("pdfs/*.pdf", recursive=True)

for ff in files:
    # get the evince call
    command = f"evince --fullscreen {ff}"
    # open the pdf
    process_cat = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, shell = True)
    next = input("Keep viewing files? Y/N")
    # close the pdf
    os.kill(process_cat.pid, signal.SIGKILL)

    if next != "Y":
        break
```

Comment: Have a look at the pywin32 module. I have never tried what you ask for myself but it looks like it is possible: https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2014/10/20/pywin32-how-to-bring-a-window-to-front/.

Comment: Thanks. I should have added I'm working with Linux, though at the minute I'm trying to take a similar appproach to that described in the link

Answer (score 1):

**idea 1: use of browser**

No idea if this will help, but are you wedded to a linux shell approach, would viewing in a web browser perhaps work better?

If so, I was wondering if this package might help?

```
import webbrowser
files = glob.glob("pdfs/*.pdf", recursive=True)

for ff in files:
    webbrowser.open_new(ff)
    # etc
```

**idea 2: direct display of PNG**

Would conversion to PNG and then direct display of the image file from python itself also be an alternative? This post may help in that case: [View pdf image in an iPython Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19470099/view-pdf-image-in-an-ipython-notebook)

Comment: That would work, mostly. Though in this case I needed finer grained control, such as dual viewing of the pdfs, which my webbrowser doesn't offer.

Comment: Just thinking out loud, but what about conversion to PNG and then directly viewing the PNG fromn python? Does this post help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19470099/view-pdf-image-in-an-ipython-notebook