# ReportLab printing report page in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, reportlab

I am wondering if its possible to have a ReportLab SimpleDocTemplace() page (or whole file) printed out in the Jupyter Notebook cell output?

Heres the abstracted code I have:

```
pdf_filename = "report_layout_example.pdf"
pdf = SimpleDocTemplate(pdf_filename, pagesize=A4, leftMargin=72, rightMargin=72, topMargin=72, bottomMargin=72)

# Create a list to populate with PDF elements
pdf_elements_list = []

# Set up the document's styles
styles = getSampleStyleSheet()

...

pdf_elements_list.extend([..])

...

pdf_bytes = BytesIO()

pdf.build(pdf_elements_list)

page_number = 1

images = pdf2image.convert_from_path(pdf_filename, dpi=96)

display(images[0])
```

This is what I've tried from an example, but doesn't work. Additional question, is it possible to replicate it in Google Colab? Thank you!

I tried to do the magic with pdf2image as shown previously, but didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried using Wand? See about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19470377/8508004). If that doesn't help, please specify if you want this to work in modern Jupyter **or** Google Colab? They are not the same thing. Most of your post is about Jupyter and then you ask about Google Colab. You can get temporary sessions for modern Jupyter by clicking on many of the '`launch binder`' badges [here](https://mybinder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/sample_repos.html). Install by running `%pip install Wand` in a new cell in your notebook there and restart the kernel and try the import.

Comment: Follow-up: I just tested the installation and import process I described at the end of my last comment in a temporary anonymous session served by the MyBinder service like [you'll get if you click here](http://notebooks.gesis.org/binder/v2/gh/binder-examples/requirements/HEAD). Be sure to download anything useful your make in the session back to your local machine so that you can upload it again in a new session later. You can just drag-and-drop into the file panel from your local computer to upload. I didn't test the next steps there yet.