# Converting first page of TIFFs to ocr PDFs and extracting specific text position

Tags: r, powershell, ocr, text-mining, renaming

I would like to convert only the first page of multiple TIFFs into an OCR PDF. What tools/cmdlets/functions can I use in R or PowerShell to convert ONLY the first page of each TIFF into a PDF?

From a given PDF (1 for each TIFF) I text mine a file number which is always listed on the second line of the first page, and I rename the PDF using file number I extracted.

I'm sure this can be improved on.
My solution so far accomplishes most of what i wanted to do, except for the ocr conversion...which I can still do using Adobe Acrobat XI Pro, and generating .txt files, which I'm doing in R. However, it would be nice to have everything through powershell.

**PART 1: convert page 1 of TIFF to a PDF**

```
#TIFF source folder
$source = 'C:\Data\PROJECTS\'

# Select TIFFs folder
Get-ChildItem -Path $source -filter *.tif | %{ convert "$($_.FullName -Replace ".tif+$", ".tif[0]")"  "$($_.FullName -Replace ".tif+$", ".pdf")" }
```

the [0] is an index used to refer to the 1st page, which i learnt from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809314/imagemagick-is-converting-only-the-first-page-of-the-pdf)

**PART 2: Convert PDF to OCR PDF**
I'm doing this in Adobe Acrobat Pro Batch Wizard

**PART 3: Convert PDF to TXT**
Currently doing this in R

**PART 4: Rename PDF using line 2 of TXT** make a directory list first with two columns, one with the TXT name and the other with the PDF name.

```
# Get the second line from every text file


$Files = Import-CSV 'C:\Data\PROJECTS\dirlist.csv' -Header ("TxtName","PdfName")

ForEach($file in $Files)
{
    $newName = Get-Content -Path $file.TxtName | Select-Object -Index 1
    $newName2 = $newName + ".pdf"
    Rename-Item $file.PdfName $newName2
}
```

where -Index 1 is used to refer to the second line of the text file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this can be improved on.
My solution so far accomplishes most of what i wanted to do, except for the ocr conversion...which I can still do using Adobe Acrobat XI Pro, and generating .txt files, which I'm doing in R. However, it would be nice to have everything through powershell.

**PART 1: convert page 1 of TIFF to a PDF**

```
#TIFF source folder
$source = 'C:\Data\PROJECTS\'

# Select TIFFs folder
Get-ChildItem -Path $source -filter *.tif | %{ convert "$($_.FullName -Replace ".tif+$", ".tif[0]")"  "$($_.FullName -Replace ".tif+$", ".pdf")" }
```

the [0] is an index used to refer to the 1st page, which i learnt from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809314/imagemagick-is-converting-only-the-first-page-of-the-pdf)

**PART 2: Convert PDF to OCR PDF**
I'm doing this in Adobe Acrobat Pro Batch Wizard

**PART 3: Convert PDF to TXT**
Currently doing this in R

**PART 4: Rename PDF using line 2 of TXT** make a directory list first with two columns, one with the TXT name and the other with the PDF name.

```
# Get the second line from every text file


$Files = Import-CSV 'C:\Data\PROJECTS\dirlist.csv' -Header ("TxtName","PdfName")

ForEach($file in $Files)
{
    $newName = Get-Content -Path $file.TxtName | Select-Object -Index 1
    $newName2 = $newName + ".pdf"
    Rename-Item $file.PdfName $newName2
}
```